# CUPS Not reaching printer unless printer powered on and off

Tags: printing

I'm having an issue with my network printer in that CUPS can't seem to reach the printer unless I power it off, and power it back on.   Anything remaining in the print queue will print after a reboot of the printer.

Scanning software (xsane) doesn't have this issue, as I can scan at anytime.

```
HP-ENVY-m7-Notebook:~/Documents/Taxes/2014$ avahi-browse -a -v -t -r
Server version: avahi 0.6.31; Host name: brendan-HP-ENVY-m7-Notebook.local
E Ifce Prot Name                                          Type                 Domain
+ wlp3s0 IPv4 Brother MFC-J475DW                            Web Site             local
+ wlp3s0 IPv4 Brother MFC-J475DW                            _scanner._tcp        local
+ wlp3s0 IPv4 Brother MFC-J475DW                            Internet Printer     local
+ wlp3s0 IPv4 Brother MFC-J475DW                            UNIX Printer         local
+ wlp3s0 IPv4 Brother MFC-J475DW                            PDL Printer          local
+ wlp3s0 IPv6 brendan-HP-ENVY-m7-Notebook [18:5e:0f:99:9b:d3] Workstation          local
+ wlp3s0 IPv4 brendan-HP-ENVY-m7-Notebook [18:5e:0f:99:9b:d3] Workstation          local
= wlp3s0 IPv6 brendan-HP-ENVY-m7-Notebook [18:5e:0f:99:9b:d3] Workstation          local
   hostname = [brendan-HP-ENVY-m7-Notebook.local]
   address = [2601:643:8302:652a:15b6:6ed7:da55:3936]
   port = [9]
   txt = []
= wlp3s0 IPv4 brendan-HP-ENVY-m7-Notebook [18:5e:0f:99:9b:d3] Workstation          local
   hostname = [brendan-HP-ENVY-m7-Notebook.local]
   address = [10.0.0.230]
   port = [9]
   txt = []
Failed to resolve service 'Brother MFC-J475DW' of type '_http._tcp' in domain 'local': Timeout reached
Failed to resolve service 'Brother MFC-J475DW' of type '_scanner._tcp' in domain 'local': Timeout reached
Failed to resolve service 'Brother MFC-J475DW' of type '_ipp._tcp' in domain 'local': Timeout reached
Failed to resolve service 'Brother MFC-J475DW' of type '_printer._tcp' in domain 'local': Timeout reached
Failed to resolve service 'Brother MFC-J475DW' of type '_pdl-datastream._tcp' in domain 'local': Timeout reached
: All for now
: Cache exhausted
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was a name resolving failure.  Fixed by statically assigning an IP to the printer and changing the connection info to the ip.

lpd://BRW00234EA65E02/BINARY_P1

to

lpd://PRINTERIPADDRESS/BINARY_P1